# $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(y)\, dy \right)= f(h(x))h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to prove the following, interesting, relation:

> $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(y)\, dy \right)= f(h(x))h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x)$

I tried to integrate by parts the RHS, but i don't get anythink usefull, i think.
\begin{align*}
&\int f(h(x))h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x)\, dx\\ &= f(h(x))h(x)-\int f'(h(x))h'(x)h(x)\, dx - f(g(x))g(x)+\int f'(g(x))g'(x)g(x)\, dx\end{align*}

Do you have any hints?

**Edit**

Following the hint. Let $F$ be an antiderivative for $f$ then
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(y)\, dy\right) &=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(F(h(x))-F(g(x)) \right)\\
&= f(h(x))h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: it seems $\frac{d}{dx}$ would be a reasonable notation here as the differentiated function is only a function of $x$ (not $y$)

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Ok, i'll edit that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Let $F$ be an anti-derivative for $f$. Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll accept in two minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the multivariate chain rule.

Write $I(s,t) = \int_{g(s)}^{h(t)} f(y) \: dy$.

Then differentiate $I(w(x))$ with $w(x) = (x,x)$.